# 50053 incomplete dimension binding

Tags: json, sapui5

Hello guys i have a problem with displaying my pie chart, when i try to add more data into the pie chart this error occurs, i need your expertise on this matter

this is my controller code. and the error message is

> [50053] - Incomplete dimensions binding

```
  onInit: function() {
             this._setupSelectionList();


//           2.Create a JSON Model and set the data
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("http://lssinh000.sin3.sap.corp:8000/SAP_LE/lionExpress/Volunteer/Services/request.xsjs");

            var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idpiechart");



//           3. Create Viz dataset to feed to the data to the graph
            var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                dimensions : [{

                        name : 'Status',
                    value : "{Status}",



                    name : 'StartDate',
                    value : '{StartDate}'



                            }],

                measures : [{
                    name : 'reqID',
                    value : '{reqID}',

                },],

                data : {
                    path : "/Status"
                }
            });     
            oVizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
            oVizFrame.setModel(oModel); 

//           4.Set Viz properties
            oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
                title:{
                    text : "Delivery Summary"
                },
                 plotArea: {
                    colorPalette : d3.scale.category20().range(),
                    drawingEffect: "glossy"
                     }});

            var feedSize = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                  'uid': "size",
                  'type': "Measure",
                  'values': ["reqID"]
                }), 
                feedColor = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                  'uid': "color",
                  'type': "Dimension",
                  'values': ["Status"]
                }),
                feedValue = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                    'uid': "value",
                    'type': "Dimension",
                    'values': ["StartDate"]




                });   
            oVizFrame.addFeed(feedSize);
            oVizFrame.addFeed(feedColor);
            oVizFrame.addFeed(feedValue);
            //this.getView().byId("idPopOver").connect(oVizFrame.getVizUid());
        },
```

Comment: [SAP archive](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3851432) for same error.

Comment: Please, don't post pictures of pure textual messages. I edited your post to replace the image with the message as a quote

Answer (score 3):

In the dataset, the name attribute has to be same as in the values arrays of the feeds.